# MVC 3 - Trying to pass Model between 'sibling' partials with ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MessagingContainer that is going to display an Inbox and Outbox partial view.  The Inbox and Outbox will toggle within the div on a click event.  Since the Inbox is getting rendered on load, passing the Model is easy.

MessagingContainer -

```
<div id="messagingContainer">
@{
    Html.RenderPartial(@"~Inbox.cshtml", Model);
}</div>
```

There is a link to get to the Outbox that will trigger an ajax event.

```
$('#outBox_@(instanceId)').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Messaging/GetOutbox',
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#messagingContainer').html(result);                  
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert('Failed Method: MessagingController.GetOutbox');
            }
        });
    });
```

The Model has multiple properties and objects in it so trying to recreate it as a JSON array would be long and tedious.  My only thought right now is to pass in the Model.Id to the controller, re-fetching the Model object and then passing that newly fetched Model to the Outbox partial.

I was just curious if there was a more trixy way to to accomplish this that I haven't come across yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might suggest that you consider having separate inbox/outbox actions with the same or different views, then use `Html.Action()` to render the Inbox when in your index action, delivering just the partial HTML when you toggle to the outbox.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var pageModel = new PageModel { ... };
    return View(pageModel);
}

public ActionResult GetInbox()
{
    var mailboxModel = new InboxModel { ... };
    return PartialView( "_Mailbox", mailboxModel );
}

public ActionResult GetOutbox()
{
    var mailboxModel = new OutboxModel { ... };
    return PartialView( "_Mailbox", mailboxModel );
}
```

View (index)

```
 <div id="messagingContainer">
 @{
       Html.RenderAction("getinbox");
 }
 </div>
```

Your AJAX code basically remains the same, but you are only rendering the partial HTML for just the outbox in the response and you can probably reuse a fair amount of the code for your Inbox/Outbox actions, likely including the partial view itself.